# How to translate "with which", "to which" "by which", etc

Tags: português-brasileiro

Often in English, I use constructions such as "to which", "by which", "from which", "with which". For example, in the story The Mortal Immortal by Mary Shelley, there is the sentence "[I] laughed at the superstitious fears **with which** he was regarded by the vulgar". Here are a few more examples:

1. You can use my lantern **with which** you will see the light.
2. I will withdraw to a place **in which** there is only sorrow.

Is there some table or reference that explains how to translate these into Brazilian Portuguese?

Comment: Read the chapter on relative clauses in any grammar book. [Example, see page 365](https://archive.org/details/gramaticadeusosd0000neve/page/365/mode/1up).

Answer (score 3):

*with which*, by which, in which etc., ***will depend on an antecedent noun, because in Portuguese the word **qual** agrees in gender and number.*** There are many other prepositions that could be used. But these are a start.

- These are the hands **with which** I till the soil.
- **Essas são** as mãos **com** **as quais** cultivo a terra. [plural, feminine]
- The clock **by which** I tell time is there.
- O relogio **pelo qual** sei que horas são está lá. [singular, masculine]

So: as quais, os quais, a qual, o qual

for **in** which, it's **no** qual, **nos** quais, **na** qual and **nas** quais

for **by which**, it's **pelo qual, pelos quais, pela qual and pelas quais**

Of course, there are others like: **from or of which**, which is just **do qual, dos quais, da qual, das quais**.

So, that's how it works. I did not provide an example of every one. Just the pattern. My sample sentences are not the best possible ones but they get the point across.

Answer (score 0):

With the right prepositions + "a/o qual".

For example: "Você pode usar a minha lanterna **com a qual** você verá a luz"

You can also use: no/na qual, do/da qual, pelo/pela qual etc!